# Age of Empires 2 HD not working good

Tags: wine, games

I have Ubuntu 13.04. I have just installed Age of Empires 2 HD on wine 1.5.29. I can start the game and open the campaigns but the window where the action should be is black after that:

[image: Screenshot showing action window of the game in black]

Is this a problem with wine, with the game or with Ubuntu?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a known problem, you have to put `-nostartup` in the launch properties/ commandline or your map will not render. For more information see the [winehq database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28008), which is better for help with wine gaming than askubuntu ;)

Comment: how to set -nostartup, I am new to linux, could you please help me ?

Comment: Are you using steam, then use https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947, in case you're using the commandline http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-5e3910facdfcb1708103ac8b3d8012a8d86b5c39

Comment: @AkhilVSuku: It is an option to the game main executable `AoK HD.exe`, so on the command line you want to change into the installation directory of the game, and then you want to run `wine 'AoK HD.exe' -nostartup`.